# Why does sourcing this file behave differently the second time?

Tags: bash

Starting with this directory structure:

```
 $ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── 2
│       └── foo.jar
└── a
    └── b
        └── c
            └── setAlias
```

The goal is to come up with the contents of setAlias, so I can source the file, and it will create an alias that runs `java -jar /absolute/path/to/foo.jar`

Here's what I have so far:

```
FOO="java -jar $(realpath $(dirname $_)/../../../1/2/foo.jar)"
echo "Setting Alias:"
echo "    foo -> $FOO"
alias foo='$FOO'
```

If I source `setAlias` from its own directly, everything works fine.  But if I set it from the root directory, I have to run it twice before the absoulute path is resolved:

```
$ source a/b/c/setAlias 
realpath: ./../../../1/2/foo.jar: No such file or directory
Setting Alias:
    foo -> java -jar 

$ source a/b/c/setAlias 
Setting Alias:
    foo -> java -jar /home/MatrixManAtYrService/1/2/foo.jar
```

If I do this from `./a/b/c` the path is resolved on the first try.

What is happening here?  Why does realpath take two tries to find the file?

Comment: The bash manpage has contained the following line for a *very* long time: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions." IOW, do *not* use aliases.  Just stop.

Comment: I will be sure to take that to heart.  I'm not sure why i didn't think to just export a function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange thing to do, but it's easily explained. Here's an excerpt from `man bash` under *Special Parameters*

> `$_` [..] expands  to the last argument to the  previous  command,  after  expansion. [...]

In other words, it refers to the last argument of the most recently executed command:

```
$ echo foo bar baz
foo bar baz

$ echo $_
baz
```

In your case, you run some arbitrary command not shown in your post, followed by `source` twice:

```
$ true foobar           # $_ now becomes "foobar"    
$ source a/b/c/setAlias # fails because $_ is "foobar", sets $_ to a/b/c/setAlias
$ source a/b/c/setAlias # works because $_ is now "a/b/c/setAlias"
```

In other words, your `source` will only work when preceded by a command that uses the value you require of `$_` as its last argument. This could be anything:

```
$ wc -l a/b/c/setAlias  # also sets $_ to a/b/c/setAlias
4
$ source a/b/c/setAlias # Works, because $_ is set to the expected value
```

Maybe you wanted to [get the current script's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within) instead?

Comment: I had it in my head that `$_` would give me the argument to `source`, from which I could construct the path I need.  It seemed to work in most cases because usually the previous command was `cd a/b/c`  The post you linked to shows how to get what I was after.  Thanks.